# LaTeX table too wide, how can I make it fit?

Tags: latex

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{proof}
\usepackage[left=0.60in, right=0.60in, top=0.65in, bottom=0.65in, footskip=0.1in]{geometry}


\title{Peergrade 1}
\author{anonymous}
\date{September 2020}
\begin{document}


\maketitle
\section{Exercise 1}

\begin{tiny}
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
A & B & C & A -\textgreater B & B -\textgreater $\sim$C & A -\textgreater $\sim$C & C -\textgreater $\sim$A & (A -\textgreater  $\sim$C) /\textbackslash (C -\textgreater $\sim$A) & (B -\textgreater $\sim$C) -\textgreater ((A -\textgreater $\sim$C) /\textbackslash (C -\textgreater $\sim$A)) & Prop 1 \\ \hline
T & T & T & T                 & F                       & F                       & F                       & F                                                                    & T                                                                                                             & T      \\ \hline
T & T & F & T                 & T                       & T                       & T                       & T                                                                    & T                                                                                                             & T      \\ \hline
T & F & T & F                 & F                       & F                       & F                       & F                                                                    & T                                                                                                             & T      \\ \hline
T & F & F & F                 & T                       & T                       & T                       & T                                                                    & T                                                                                                             & T      \\ \hline
F & T & T & T                 & F                       & T                       & T                       & T                                                                    & T                                                                                                             & T      \\ \hline
F & T & F & T                 & T                       & T                       & T                       & T                                                                    & T                                                                                                             & T      \\ \hline
F & F & T & T                 & F                       & T                       & T                       & T                                                                    & T                                                                                                             & T      \\ \hline
F & F & F & T                 & T                       & T                       & T                       & T                                                                    & T                                                                                                             & T      \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{tiny}



\end{document}
```

Can anyone help me so that the table fits in LaTeX? It almost fits, but half of the last column part goes outiside the paper. I have already tried to add /small and /footnotesize, but it doesnt work.

Comment: Can you tell us your documentclass?

Comment: What is "*…fits in LaTeX*" supposed to mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Please have a look at http://betterposters.blogspot.de/2012/08/the-data-prison.html how to design nice looking tables*

---

You could use a `tabularx` and let latex adjust the size:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{proof}
\usepackage[left=0.60in, right=0.60in, top=0.65in, bottom=0.65in, footskip=0.1in]{geometry}


\usepackage{tabularx}

\title{Peergrade 1}
\author{anonymous}
\date{September 2020}
\begin{document}


\maketitle
\section{Exercise 1}

\begin{tiny}
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|X|l|}
\hline
A & B & C & A -\textgreater B & B -\textgreater $\sim$C & A -\textgreater $\sim$C & C -\textgreater $\sim$A & (A -\textgreater $\sim$C) /\textbackslash (C -\textgreater $\sim$A) & (B -\textgreater $\sim$C) -\textgreater ((A -\textgreater $\sim$C) /\textbackslash (C -\textgreater $\sim$A)) & Prop 1 \\ \hline
T & T & T & T & F & F & F & F & T & T \\ \hline
T & T & F & T & T & T & T & T & T & T \\ \hline
T & F & T & F & F & F & F & F & T & T \\ \hline
T & F & F & F & T & T & T & T & T & T \\ \hline
F & T & T & T & F & T & T & T & T & T \\ \hline
F & T & F & T & T & T & T & T & T & T \\ \hline
F & F & T & T & F & T & T & T & T & T \\ \hline
F & F & F & T & T & T & T & T & T & T \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{tiny}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just complementing the answer, if the table is very large, it's possible to rotate the sheet by using pdflscape:

```
\usepackage{pdflscape}
...

\begin{landscape}
(Your Table)
\end{landscape}
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{proof}
\usepackage[left=0.60in, right=0.60in, top=0.65in, bottom=0.65in, footskip=0.1in]{geometry}

\title{Peergrade 1}
\author{anonymous}
\date{September 2020}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Exercise 1}

%\begin{tiny}
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|p{20mm}|p{22mm}|l|}
\hline
A & B & C & A -\textgreater B & B -\textgreater $\sim$C %
& A -\textgreater $\sim$C & C -\textgreater $\sim$A %
& (A -\textgreater $\sim$C) \par /\textbackslash (C -\textgreater $\sim$A) %
& (B -\textgreater $\sim$C) \par -\textgreater ((A -\textgreater $\sim$C) \par %
/\textbackslash (C -\textgreater $\sim$A)) & Prop 1 \\ \hline
T & T & T & T & F & F & F & F & T & T \\ \hline
T & T & F & T & T & T & T & T & T & T \\ \hline
T & F & T & F & F & F & F & F & T & T \\ \hline
T & F & F & F & T & T & T & T & T & T \\ \hline
F & T & T & T & F & T & T & T & T & T \\ \hline
F & T & F & T & T & T & T & T & T & T \\ \hline
F & F & T & T & F & T & T & T & T & T \\ \hline
F & F & F & T & T & T & T & T & T & T \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
%\end{tiny}
\end{document}
```

I have only edited the alignment of the 8th and 9th column (`p{20mm}|p{22mm}`) and added three `\par` in the first cell in such columns (out of dollar signs, you're typing *text* in the cells).

[image: screenshot of output pdf]

Anyway the solution with `tabularx` by @samcarter is very good.